# Create a list of the unique identifier for each duplicate value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In my Google Sheet I have got the Unique values and a count of the duplicates but I want to create a column that has the unique ID (UID) for each of duplicate values so I can decide on further analysis.

Using `=VLOOKUP(D2,A$2:B,2,FALSE)` I can get the first one, but how to I get the others?

A test sheet is in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WnGEsuuJcKsHVhpyYCX5EpmIxuKQEst5XVXgeETzxJ4/edit?usp=sharing

For [image]

I'd like to see the UID column for `PR120973-2^388.674` to be `{1,6,20,25}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FILTER`/`TEXTJOIN`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(B:B,A:A=D2))
```

[image]

Comment: Wonderful, you answered quicker than I can click accept answer!